# How to get a different background on Xbox Series S every time I login?

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s

I have a series S. I want to select a bunch of images and I want a different custom background every time I login. If I choose one now, it's always the same image.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to automatically change the background each time. You will have to manually select your preferred background.